# Pass state from one component to another stateless component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I tried to summarize my problem in the code below. My real code it is too big, so I developed another similar code in way to solve this problem.
I have a loggin page where the user has to type "True" or "False" to update the state fom this component. 
I need to pass this state to the "Route" component, that will verify what page is going to be rendered. If the parameter received from the Login component is "True", then Home page will be rendered. If it is "False" Login page will be rendered.

From my understanding, I have to pass props from childreen to parent component, but I am not being able to solve this problem.

App.jsx (Component)

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Routes from './Routes'

export default props =>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Routes />
        </div>    
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Routes.jsx (Component)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router'
import Login from './Login';
import Home from './Home';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
            isAuthenticated() ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ): (
                <Redirect to={{pathname: "/login", state: {from: props.location }}} />
            )}
    />
)

const Routes = () =>
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path='/home' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Redirect from='*' to='/home' />
    </Switch>

export default Routes;
```

Home.jsx (Component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Home extends Component {
    render (){
        return (
            <h1>This is the HOME page</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

Login.jsx (Component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Routes from './Routes'

export default class Login extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userLoggedIn: false
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

     handleChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let stateName = e.target.name
        let stateValue = e.target.value
        console.log(e.target, e.target.value)
        this.setState({ [stateName]: stateValue})
    }

    render(){
        console.log('esse estado é',this.state.userLoggedIn)
        return( 
            <div>
                <div>This is the Login Page</div>
                <label>State Test</label>
                <input placeholder="true or false" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
                <Link to={{pathname: "/home"}}>
                    <button >Go To Home Page</button>
                </Link>
            </div>   
        )        
    }
}
```

What do I expect?
When the user type "True" in the Login page, Home page must be rendered.
When the user type "False" in the Login page, Login page must be rendered.

Comment: you may want to use redux to store your login information and render component depending on its state

Comment: Refer to this [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) and where is `isAuthenticated` method defined?

Comment: @Jose - I have added answer, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @tarzenchugh sorry for the late respose.
Thanks for your answer....I understood your answer, althought I wasn't able to solve my problem...I have been strugling on that for weeks.
Anyway, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code and [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-redirects-auth-d2egn)

If user enters false, then he will not be redirected as he is already on `Login` page.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

function AuthExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <AuthButton />
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/home">Home Page</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
  }
};

const AuthButton = withRouter(({ history }) =>
  fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
    <p>
      Welcome!{" "}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          fakeAuth.signout(() => history.push("/"));
        }}
      >
        Sign out
      </button>
    </p>
  ) : (
    <p>You are not logged in.</p>
  )
);

function Home() {
  return <h3>This is the HOME page</h3>;
}

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    redirectToReferrer: false,
    input: ""
  };

  login = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.input === "true") {
      fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
        this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
    }
  };

  handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ [target.name]: target.value });
  };

  render() {
    let { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
    let { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;

    if (redirectToReferrer) return <Redirect to={from} />;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>This is the Login Page</div>
        <label>State Test</label>
        <br />
        <input
          placeholder="true or false"
          name={"input"}
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.login}>Go To Home Page</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AuthExample;
```

Hope that helps!!!